# Vehicle tracking system in Android

Tags: java, android, android-maps

in my college sir has given topic to do for final year project.

So thing is that, can it be possible in Android?

> Tracking any vehicle which having android device, so we can able to
>   find vehicles current location

Please suggest me, guide me.

Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of open-source Android projects with the same purpose.  You can start with http://www.google.es/search?q=android+tracker+application+code that gives you this link http://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/ among others

Comment: Search for GPS tracking and probably storing the current location server side.

Comment: Of course it is possible, it is dead simple. The App on the Mobile reads the Location Service of the Mobile (fed by assisted GPS usually), it calculates how much changed since last time it communicated. If the Distance is large or timespan is long you sent a position message to a server over data plan. Note that purpose build onboard units in fleet management systems are typically much more sophisticated - btw: for a final year project I would expect some more requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Android can have location updates, so if a software installed on the android device can send GPS coordinates to a server and hence area information, it can be done. It can be done with an android device that has GPS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; it's a well-established feature.  On my Android phone, I commonly use...
1. Google Maps -- Shows me where I am, on a map.  Plus searching, etc.
2. Google "My Tracks" -- Uses GPS to make a map of my bicycle and hiking trips.
3. TreKing 4 - Uses GPS to connect me with bus and train information in Chicago.

Some taxi companies use this to keep track of where all their taxis are:  http://www.instamapper.com/

In what creative new way would you like to use GPS information?